# Highcharts range selector button not working

Tags: highcharts

I have a graph with a range selector 6h, 1d, 7d and all. When the graph is loaded you can't press on all, only on the first three. All becomes available after you pressed 1d or 7d.

```
$('#chart-ranked').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        events: {
            load: function () {
                this.rangeSelector.clickButton(0);
            }
        },
        height: 500
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Player Skill Rating Progression',
        x: -20
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Updated hourly',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return moment(this.value).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM");
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Skill Rating'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: true,
        buttons: [{
            type: 'minute',
            count: 60 * 6,
            text: '6h'
        },{
            type: 'day',
            count: 1,
            text: '1d'
        }, {
            type: 'day',
            count: 7,
            text: '7d'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormatter: function () {
            return '<tr><td style="color:' + this.color + ';padding:0;">' + this.series.name + ': </td><td style="padding:0 0 0 4px;"><strong>' + this.y + ' Skill Rating</strong></td></tr>';
        },
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'center',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Ranked Solo Duel',
        data: jsonData.ranked_duel
    }, {
        name: 'Ranked Doubles',
        data: jsonData.ranked_doubles
    }, {
        name: 'Ranked Solo Standard',
        data: jsonData.ranked_solo_standard
    }, {
        name: 'Ranked Standard',
        data: jsonData.ranked_standard
    }],
    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            theme: {
                style: {
                    color: '#E0E0E0'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                text: "Download",
                symbol: null
            }
        },
        filename: 'player_rank_progression_rating_chart',
        sourceWidth: 1200,
        sourceHeight: 1200
    }
});
```

I reproduced the issue on jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/2j4d1y20/

I am not sure if this is an bug or intentional, but I would like to fix or workaround this.

Comment: A quick fix looks like setting `rangeSelector.allButtonsEnabled: true`.

Comment: Was unaware of that option, thanks @HalvorStrand!

Comment: For now, all works properly ?